# Bypass login.microsoftonline.com using API/tokens using Power Query M function?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, access-token

I am working on a Power BI M function wherein I need to import data directly from Microsoft Graph. The M function is exactly as mentioned in [here](https://powers-hell.com/2021/08/15/authenticate-to-graph-directly-from-powerbi/)

```
(_tenantId as text, _clientId as text, _clientSecret as text, _resource as text, _grantType as text, _scope as text) as text =>
let
    Url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"&_tenantId&"/oauth2/token",
    Body = "resource="&_resource&"&client_id="&_clientId&"&grant_type="&_grantType&"&scope="&_scope&"&client_secret="&_clientSecret,
    Options = [
        Content = Text.ToBinary(Body)
    ],
    Response = Web.Contents(Url,Options),
    ParsedJson = Json.Document(Response),
    ConvertedToken = "Bearer "&ParsedJson[access_token]
in
    ConvertedToken
```

As it turns out, I don't have access to `login.microsoftonline.com` on the server I am working on. How do I bypass it? I have these extra API tokens available to be called `Secret Key Name and Secret Key` in addition to already used "Client ID", "Tenant ID", "Secret ID"

Comment: Pretty sure this would be a big security issue if you could access a MS tenant without authenticating.